# Is synchronized radiation possible?

Tags: laser, atoms, radioactivity

Could it be possible to make 2 or more radioactive atoms, maybe plutonium, emit radiation at the same time? A kind of synchronized radiation. Perhaps this can be the basis for some kind of laser too.

Comment: Spontaneous radioactive decay appears to be a truly random process. You can stimulate various reactions by hitting things with neutrons, look up neutron spallation.

Comment: Photofission with short pulsed x-ray sources might be doable.